# Server Configuration for WSO2 IOT Server with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, wso2-iot

I have a aws ubuntu server with 4gb RAM and 2gb internal memory.  I want the wso2 iot server with postgresql configuration.  What kind of configuration needed for aws ubuntu server for this requirement. As per the wso2 iot documentation, 4gb RAM and 1gb, I have configured with that configuration which is not good right now.  Please do any one tell me the what kind of server optimisation needed for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with wso2 modules, I have found that they only work for me when deployed as individual servers. I was using local VirtualBox vms so that I had Data Services on one vm, Enterprise Service Bus on another, etc. Any attempt to combine them in the installer would result in Java dependency hell.